# Copy "string" through command line

Tags: command-line, scripts

Can we copy a string with a command-line and have the ability of pasting it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> shortcut?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`xsel`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xsel/)  tool (a command-line tool to access X clipboard and selection buffers). To install it from terminal, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Then, using the following:

```
<command> | xsel -b
```

will copy the output of `<command>`  to the clipboard which can be pasted after with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

For example:

```
echo -n "string" | xsel -b
```

or, simple:

```
xsel -b <<< "string"
```

will copy to the clipboard the string `string` (I used `-n` argument for `echo` to suppress the trailing newline).

If you want to copy the text from a file named `file_name` from the current working directory:

```
cat file_name | xsel -b
```

or, simple:

```
xsel -b < file_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Install `xclip` (`sudo apt-get install xclip`)

If you want to copy text from a file, run

`xclip -sel clip < /path/to/file` ( This will copy the text to clipboard)

For more info: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip