# How to pipe/dump clipboard contents to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to pipe/dump the contents (esp. text) of the clipboard/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to a file, preferably using Bash or Perl (in order). I'd rather not use GUI applications please.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### How to pipe clipboard contents to a file?

You can do it using `xsel`. Type in terminal to install it,

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

To put the contents of a file to the clipboard use:
`xsel -b < some.txt`

To paste the contents of the `clipboard` to a file use.

```
`xsel -b >> some.txt`
```

#### Copy file content/string to clipboard

You can [go through this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/371033/127327) by [Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-rdeanu) which described how you can copy file content/string from a terminal to clipboard that can be pasted using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Reminder: If you have something very important in your clipboard, don't copy and paste text from this answer as you will regret it.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast can you please elaborate so that we can know what/how exactly can cause a problem.

Comment: The problem occurs like this
1) Copy something very long and important to your clipboard
2) Accidentally close the source of this data
3) Frantically google how to write clipboard out to a file
4) Find this post
5) Copy the example text
6) You lost your original important text

Comment: This did not work. Resulted in `xsel: Can't open display: (null) : Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Comment: @rocksNwaves I request you to tell us about what exactly you tried. As I can see it works fine for me. IMHO there might be a small misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @souravc I tried exactly what you had listed here. Word for word, step for step.

Comment: I had the same problem. Installed with the command above and used it with the second command. Did it on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). Not sure if it might be related to beeing a headless server. But actually I installed something like X11 I think and I have a GUI which I can use over VNC. It also might be related to the fact that I was logged in via SSH.

Comment: @rocksNwaves Every command that works under X needs.. well.. X server running, xsel is not an exception to this. When you do ctrl+C you are doing it in a X session. Make xsel connect to that session by exporting the DISPLAY variable, for example `DISPLAY=:0 xsel -b`. Run `echo $DISPLAY` in your X environment to know your exact DISPLAY value

Answer (score 29):

Here's a way that is done from the command line and does not require any libraries:

1. Copy your data to the clipboard.
2. Run `cat > /your/file/path` in the terminal window
3. Paste the contents to the terminal window
4. Press press `Ctrl + D`.

Tested on ubuntu.

Comment: How does this at all achieve what is asked? And how does it have any advantage over piping directly?

Comment: It pastes the contents of the clipboard into a file using bash. That's exactly what they asked for.

Comment: @d512 This is not a feasible solution in cases where I have a huge chunk of text, pasting of which could possibly freeze the terminal session and/or make me wait way longer till everything is printed on the terminal. Other major issue with this approach is that, if you have too many characters in a single line, it will be truncated.

Comment: Good solution if you do not want to install any extra tools.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham: What does *huge chunk of text* mean here? How many bytes? At what point does this method start truncating lines? Can you suggest an alternative for systems that aren't running X? I have to do this weekly (because, despite documentation, the frapping API returns HTML instead of JSON). This method handles 4k of JSON as a single line.

Comment: Tested on Manjaro (Arch Linux): working perfectly.

Comment: You may need to press CTRL-D twice for it to go through

Comment: Does not work for binary/image files.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use `xclip` (install with `sudo apt-get install xclip`) like so:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o > clipboard.txt
```

which will put the clipboard into `clipboard.txt` in the working folder.

Comment: For images you could use something like: ``xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > "`date +%Y-%m-%d_%T`.png"``.

Comment: xclip worked for me with a paste of about 200k lines from a log. xsel (accepted answer) did not

Comment: While copypasting to vim took ages (didn't finished after 10 minutes), I didn't have time to blink before `xclip` had the job done.  `xsel` didn't work.

Comment: `xclip -o > clipboard.txt` worked just fine for me

Comment: If doing this via SSH... "Can't open display: (null)"

Answer (score 1):

An other option is `gpaste` which has the advantage of being able to get several previous clipboard copies.

Install it by

```
sudo apt-get install gpaste
```

And you can recover the last copy with

```
gpaste-client get 0 > file.txt
```

Note that you can change the `0` to any number to get the other copies.

Comment: after installing, gpaste still won't work! This sucks

Comment: It's now "gpaste-client" in Ubuntu 18.04 ... cc @Russo